# How to insert a page break after n records in a group?

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

configuration (Please don't laught ) :  the technologies in use are :

- Crystal  Report 6.0.1.135
- VB6

Question : I have a report with a subreport. I am facing an issue on the subreport : when the subreport reaches the bottom of the page, the last 2 lines (records) are "hidden" by the main report Footer.

I precise that the number of hidden records depends on the footer hight. 
A workaround is to delete/hide the footer, but this is not acceptable from business decision (page number must be printed).

I suspect this is a bug.

I am trying to work around it by inserting a page break after let's say 20 records of the subreport. I am struggling to do that, anyone as a clue on this ?

Comment: Is the `Can Grow` property of the subreport enabled?

Comment: @R.McMillan : Not sure where this property is. But for sure the group grows up to the total; the problem occurs on page break

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue :

Rigth click on the Conception pane

On the Expert Section select the Group Header or Details you want to insert page break. 
[image]
Tick the Page Break Before or Page Break After ( in french in the example, Nouvelle page avant / Nouvelle page après)

You get an area where you can enter a formula that will be used for the page break ( it must return a boolean , when true , the page break occurs) 
There you can enter a formula :

[image]

This formula can refers to "magic" (in the sense of they exists in Crystal Report) keywords.

The formula below for example forces a page break every 50 Groups, but not for the last group (to avoid a blanck page).

```
Remainder(GroupNumber,50) = 0   And Not ONLASTRECORD
```

The same magic keywords exists :

```
RecordNumber
```

`GroupNumber` and `RecordNumber` are variables provided by Crystal Report obviously.

If anyone can point out a link with documentation for this old version of Crystal, I would be helpful