# Subreport to grow to main report not create new page

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have my crystal report where I added a subreport, but the challenge is, I need the subreport to grow to next page of the main report... 
Such that the first record of the subreport is on the first page, and the next record of the subreport is on page 2 of the main report... And so on...

Comment: Sounds like you need a page break after each record. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977145/how-to-insert-a-page-break-after-n-records-in-a-group) should be helpful.

Comment: @Ahmed I added a page break on both the main report and subreport, but as the subreport goes to the next record and page, it creates a blank page with the value of the next record... I however need this second value of the subreport to be on the second page of the main report as is the second record of the main report... I don't know if I'm making sense

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance that you simply need to turn off the 'Keep Object Together' format property of the subreport.
Right-click the subreport, Format Subreport...
See: https://www.screencast.com/t/k9qEmws10m

Comment: When I disable 'Keep Object Together', only one record of the subreport is shown on all pages of the main report

Comment: Turn off the New Page After.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, it sounds like the subreport is being run for every record in the main report at once and you're trying to parse the results out across the main report. I think you might need to redesign how you're main report and subreport are interacting.

If you have, say, ten records in your main report printed in the detail section and each has a unique RecordID - you'll want to link your subreport to your main report by the RecordID (and any other necessary parameters). Then add a second detail line in the main report and put your subreport there (**below** where the linked RecordID prints in the main report). As the report runs, each time the top detail line is printed in the canvas the RecordID will pass to the subreport in the next detail line and the corresponding data will print below it. The subreport would run ten separate times as the mainr eport is generated - once for each RecordId.

It's important that the RecordID be initialized in the report canvas above where the subreport is running or it won't pass to the subreport.